# Provide examples or explain why it is impossible

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, continuity

a) A continuous function defined on an open interval with range equal to a closed interval.

My example: $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(4\pi x)+\frac{1}{2}$ on $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$.
Note: I am not considering $\mathbb{R}$ an interval.

b) A continuous function defined on a closed interval with range equal to an open interval.

I think this is impossible if we exclude $\mathbb{R}$. Edit: we must also exclude unbounded intervals. By the Extreme Value Theorem, any  continuous function on a compact set attains a maximum and a minimum. Yet, the set of the points in an open interval doesn't include its supremum and infimum, a contradiction.

c) A continuous function defined on an open interval with range equal to an unbounded closed set different from $\mathbb{R}$.

My example: $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ to [0,$\infty$). Is there another function that works and has a different domain than $\mathbb{R}$?

d) A continuous defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ with range equal to $\mathbb{Q}$.

I was thinking maybe map the natural numbers to $\mathbb{Q}$ and use the rest to "fill in the gaps." Evidently, I need most help with d).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't count $\mathbb{R}$, but do you count e.g. $[0,+\infty)$ as a closed interval?

Comment: For (d), note that the image of a connected set by a continuous map is connected. (Or in this particular case: use the intermediate value theorem.)

Comment: I understand the hypocrisy, yes. However, I'm simply trying to avoid using more trivial examples that use the fact that R is open and closed.

Comment: c) Domain other than R?  Sure.  The trick in a) was to "bend" the domain so that inf(f) corresponds to "closed" point in the range to make the range close.  Do the same thing but "stretch the end to infinity.  Ex.  domain = (-2,0).  f(x) = x if x is between -2 and -1.  Iet f(x) = 1/x other wise.  The range starts "vaguely" at -2, raises to -1 where it "shears" off to a limit point, and plummets down again to negative infinity.  The range is [-1, -inf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a) I would just consider a constant function, $[a,a]$ is a closed interval. If you want an interval of positive length, $\sin$ or some variation (like yours) is the way to go. Personally I would prefer to adapt the domain to adding stuff and factors.

For b) your argument is correct for bounded intervals.

For c) you could do something with $x+\frac{1}{x}$.

For d) consider what the intermediate value theorem would mean for such a function.

Answer (score 2):

For b) think about $(\sin x)(1-1/x)$ on $[1,\infty).$

Answer (score 1):

This looks like mostly good work.

a) This is perfect as is.

b) Just excluding $\mathbb{R}$ is not enough since you can map $[0,\infty)$ to an open interval. But your argument is valid for bounded intervals.

c) If you want to find a map on a finite interval consider the map $(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$. This doesn't completely work yet but you can extend this function to $(0,2)$ in a way to make it work.

d) Take a look at the [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

c) $f(x)  = |\tan x |$ from $(-\pi/2, \pi/2) \to [0,\infty)$

d) $f(x) = 1$ would map $x\in R$ to a subset of $\mathbb Q$ and that is the best you are going to be able to do.

For all of these, there is a definition definitions of continuous that you might find useful.

$f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff for every open sub-set $V\subset Y$ the pre-image of $V$ is open.
The pre-image of $V$ is  $f^{-1}(V) = \{x\in X|f(x)\in V \}$.

Comment: $f(x)=1$ does not have a range *equal to* $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: The answer states quite clearly that $f(x)=1$ maps to a **subset** of $\mathbb Q$ and that it's the best that can be achieved, so that comment is totally pointless.

Comment: Another example for (c) is $f(x)=1/(x-x^2)$ for $x\in (0,1)$.